# jQuery orientationchange function not working

Tags: jquery, orientation-changes

Below 800px width my `#main_navigation` is hidden by CSS `display: none` in a media query. A click on the menu icon (which becomes visible below 800px) triggers this jQuery script: `jQuery('#main_navigation').slideToggle(300);`
It inserts `style:'display: block'` into that tag, and when clicked again, that changes to `style:'display: none'`.

Now, when I for example use a 1024x768 tablet/iPad, in landscape mode the menu is regularly displayed (as a horizontal list), in portrait mode it's hidden (represented by a menu icon) and displayed when I click the menu icon.

But when I click/tap the icon twice (show, then hide) in portrait mode and then turn the tablet into landscape mode, neither the icon (due to the stylesheet) *nor* the regular menu (due to the `style:'display: none'` set by jQuery) attribute are displayed: No menu at all!

So I inserted this function, hoping to simply delete/remove the `style` attribute when turning the device and thereby making the menu visible again above 800px width (i.e. the regular stylesheet and media queries are applied):

```
jQuery(window).on('orientationchange', function () {
    jQuery('#main_navigation').removeAttr('style');
});
```

But: It doesn't work, my menu tag still contains `style:'display: none'`, and therefore there is no visible menu in the described situation. Where is the error?

Comment: You should look to adjust the media queries [breakpoints](https://responsivedesign.is/develop/browser-feature-support/media-queries-for-common-device-breakpoints/) to make sure there's always one menu displayed. -- Just for you to know,  `.removeAttribute()` is not a jQuery method... It should be [`.removeAttr()`](https://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/)... But anyway, it isn't the right approach at all.

Comment: Second taught... Look for the `onresize` event to re-evaluate the width and if the "regular" menu is hidden,  use [`.show()`](https://api.jquery.com/show/) instead of trying to remove an attribute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using a condition about the current width when the display is rezized:

And if the `orientationchange` isn't working (should work), try adding the [`resize`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/resize) event.

```
jQuery(window).on('orientationchange resize', function () {
  if(jquery("body").width()>768){  // Make sure to test that width... Just a suggestion here.
    jQuery('#main_navigation').show();
  }
});
```

Comment: Yes, that works! Thanks for pointing out my mistake re `removeAttr`. Unfortunately, that alone still didn't help, but using `resize`, `show()` and the width condition made it work!  BTW, my breakpoints are okay, there *is* always a menu visible according to the media queries (also on orientation change). The problem arises only if the nav icon is tapped twice: The slideToggle() function inserts the `display` style attribute and changes it to `display: none` on the second tap. But your solution works, thank you very much!

Comment: Yes, the breakpoints comment was on fy first reading... But I then noticed the "click/tap" twice then rotate issue. So that means the show/hide is triggered by JS, not the CSS rules... So that was my "second taught" ;)